# SQL Server migration 2008 to 2016 - raiserror syntax error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, raiserror

We are going to migrate from SQL Server 2008 to 2016. I am in the process of identifying errors and I get the following error in a trigger:

> Incorrect syntax near '51001'.

I looked through the `Raiserror` documentation on the Microsoft website and it did not help. The following is the SQL. Any help would be appreciated.

```
IF (SELECT count(*) FROM dbo.u_sample_concrete ref, deleted
WHERE  ref.lab_cd =  deleted.lab_id) > 0
BEGIN
    RAISERROR 51001 ''Trigger td_tblLAB on table dbo.tblLAB:  Primary key values found in table dbo.u_sample_concrete (lab_cd).  Delete restricted; the transaction is being rolled back.''
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    RETURN
END
```

Comment: `RETURN` is unnecessary - unless you have further content in your trigger which you don't want to run when this error occurs.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but consider using ```IF (SELECT count(1)``` instead of ```IF (SELECT count(*)```

Comment: @TWP whats the reasoning behind your suggestion? It makes no difference to performance.

Comment: And learn to join properly - no one should be joining using the old-style syntax via the where clause. Nor do you need to COUNT at all - that is just a generally wasteful. Use EXISTS to determine if rows actually exist. Statement terminators are also a good habit to develop; eventually they will be required. Seems like it time to start learning best practices and doing some serious code reviews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-previousversions) does indeed show 4 things wrong with your statement.

1. The parameters must be inside brackets `raiserror()`.
2. 4 parameters are expected when `msd_id` (`51001`) is used - you are providing 2.
3. Parameters should be separated by commas `,`.
4. You are double quoting the string, when it should be single quoted.

```
RAISERROR (51001, -1,- 1, 'Trigger td_tblLAB on table dbo.tblLAB:  Primary key values found in table dbo.u_sample_concrete (lab_cd).  Delete restricted; the transaction is being rolled back.')
```

Note: its best practice now to use [`throw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) rather than `raiserror`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @DaleK's answer with the proper syntax, the problem `RAISERRROR` syntax is long obsolete. IIRC, it was deprecated 20 years ago (with the SQL Server 2000 release) and removed entirely in SQL Server 2012.

Below is a powershell script that uses the [T-SQL Script DOM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom) (also available with the [Dacfx NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx.x86/)) to identify existing T-SQL modules with invalid syntax. It won't catch problems in dynamic SQL, though.

```
$connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI"

try {

    $query = @"
SELECT 
      QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id)) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(object_id)) AS ObjectName
    , OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id, 'ExecIsQuotedIdentOn') AS ExecIsQuotedIdentOn
    , definition 
FROM sys.sql_modules;
"@

    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin\Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll"

    $connection = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)
    $command = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query, $connection)
    $connection.Open()
    $reader = $command.ExecuteReader()
    while ($reader.Read()) {

        # use TSqlParser appropriate for your SQL Server version
        $parser = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.TSql130Parser($reader["ExecIsQuotedIdentOn"])
        $parseErrors = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.ParseError]
        $scriptReader = New-Object IO.StringReader($($reader["definition"]))

        Write-Host "Parsing $($reader["ObjectName"]) ..."
        [void]$parser.Parse($scriptReader, [ref]$parseErrors)
        if($parseErrors.Count -ne 0) {
            Write-Host "Parsing errors for object $($reader["ObjectName"]): $($parseErrors | ConvertTo-Json)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        }

    }
    $connecton.Close()
}    
catch {
    throw
}
```